# Copy folder to publish locations bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In the Visual Studio solution explorer it is possible to set "Build action" and "Copy To Output Directory" for files when viewing the file properties:

[image]

My question is: How can I tell Visual Studio to copy the complete folder and sub folder/files to the output directory?

If I view the properties of the folder the options are not there:

[image]

I tried using a post build command:

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)Lib/XULRunner21_0" "$(OutDir)XULRunner21_0/" /E /I /F /Y
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)Lib/ABCGecko.dll" "$(OutDir)" /E /I /F /Y
```

The files are copied before compiling, but not during publishing so that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is very old, but I struggled to find a solution when this should be easy enough. If you want to copy a folder to the **Publish** directory, with all the files inside, you can do the following in the **.csproj** file:

```
<Target Name="CopyYourFolderAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="XCOPY $(ProjectDir)YourFolder\*.* $(PublishDir)\YourFolder\ /S /Y" />
</Target>
```

Now, `YourFolder` will appear in the publish folder. This was tested using .NET6 and VS 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Build action for each file to "Content". Then they will be distributed to the output folder (any the sub folder in your project where they are located will also be created under the output folder)

Comment: I understand, but for a single file it is no problem, but this folder has a lot of subfolders that contain folders and files. I know it is possible to set "Content" for each file by hand, but that would be a hell of a job for 1600 files

Comment: I see. I noticed that you had build action to "None". Could you zip the content and let the application unzip and delete the zip file after installation? pseudo: if (IsFileExists("1600files.zip")) { Unzip "1600files.zip"; Delete "1600files.zip" }

Comment: Thanks for the option, but I think it should be part of deployment instead of copy the files from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can arbitrarily extend your build process as described here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

For example, in your project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
  <Exec Command="XCOPY ..." />
  <Exec Command="XCOPY ..." />
</Target>
```

Comment: Given what he is trying to do, `AfterPublish` might be more suitable, since he might delete all items on publish.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: I have just seen your last comment ("The files are copied before compiling, but not during publishing so that does not work."), so publishing problem still exists. However; We should be able to extend the visual studio build process for BeforePublish and AfterPublish target names in order to fix publishing problem as [described here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx)

This is how you can tell Visual Studio to copy the complete folder and sub folder/files to the output directory.

First add your folder(This is my folder XULRunner21_0) to your project with all the items added to your project, and then go to your project's Properties>Build Events and write the following command line into Post-build event command line area. After building the solution, you should see under bin folder of your project XULRunner21_0 folder will be created with all the items in it.

That is all, hope it helps.

```
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)XULRunner21_0\*" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)XULRunner21_0\"
```